# Is there a php function code to replace a browser url

Tags: javascript, php, curl

i want to replace a url in a browser with a text, example replace https://facebook.com in a browser url to  "im here" without protocol.

Comment: You cannot do that because 1) PHP is serverside language and cannot affect the browser that way; 2) There are security issues in being able to replace the URL bar with things other than the location of a page, and 3) users like me would want you to rot in prison for crimes against usability, sanity and common sense. This belongs with "I would like the hotel shampoo bottles to contain pink acid" and "Bridges would be so much more fun if they were made of jelly".

Comment: You flagged with javascript and PHP but the question-title actually specifies PHP. For what are you now trying to find a solution? As @Amadan already pointed out: it is not possible from PHP-side.

Comment: Do you mean redirect?

Comment: no there isn't. and there isn't in any other language, either. just imagine why: you could be on `realyrealybadsitetryingtostealyoureverything.com` pretending to be google and you wouldn't even know. what you're trying to do is impossible by design, and there is no valid reason at all to want to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot replace a url with a text without any protocol like that because php is serverside scripting language it can only affect the browser.